# Problem with hibernate example - configuration file not found

Tags: hibernate

I'm doing hibernate course on udemy. I created hibernate configuration file. But it doesn't seem to loaded or seen.
I receive this:

```
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
wrz 17, 2021 5:55:28 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector <clinit>
SEVERE: null
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/hibernate-db</property> <!-- BD Mane -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property> <!-- DB Driver -->
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property> <!-- DB User Name -->
        <property name="connection.password">password</property> <!-- DB Password -->
        
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> <!-- DB Dialect -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> <!-- create / create-drop / update -->
        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
        <property name="format_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->
        
        <mapping class="kamianowski.Student"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Code from main method:

```
Student student = new Student("Paul", "Wall", "paul@luv2code.com");
        Set<String> theImages = student.getImages();
        theImages.add("image1.jpg");
        theImages.add("image2.jpg");
        theImages.add("image3.jpg");
        theImages.add("image4.jpg");
        theImages.add("image5.jpg");

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

STudent class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

//  Tell the hibernate we are mapping a collection
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "image", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private Set<String> images = new HashSet<>();

// getters, setters and constructors
}
```

I don't know why this is not even loaded. I putted this file in the src/main/resources directory.

Comment: Did you add the folder `src/main/resources` to your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass --illegal-access=permit in VM arguments while running and check if it's solving the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).